# Cloning RFID tags with Raspberry Pi 3 and RC522?

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, rfid, nfc

I've looked around a lot now and can barely find any information on how to clone RFID tags with the Raspberry Pi, I've seen plenty of content on how to do it using an Arduino but I would really rather not have to buy and learn to use an Arduino when I already have a perfectly fine Pi to use. I've set up my Pi with the RC522 reader and have confirmed that it does in fact read and write data, I am just struggling to find any scripts on GitHub or otherwise that will clone an RFID tag. Have I overlooked something? Will I have to try and write the script myself?

Comment: tutorial [here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/) seems fairly comprehensive. and [here](https://github.com/ondryaso/pi-rc522) as well

Comment: These are the tutorials and repositories that I used yet I still have no idea how to clone the tags? My RC522 is already set up and working, that's not the issue I'm having, I just want to know how to clone the tags using the Pi.

Comment: `Will I have to try and write the script myself?` have you tried? You'll get a lot more  satisfaction from writing the code yourself, rather than `git clone someone-elses-work.git` :p

Comment: Your right, but I can't actually code python and the project is more of a hobby, not enough to warrant learning it, maybe one day, but for now GitHub is my only hope for scripts that do what I need, and if what I need ain't there I'm screwed!

Comment: @JayBuckel: Try to look at this from another perspective. You've asked for someone to do "pick and shovel" work for you: performing a proper Google search, and reading enough of the results to get started at least. And in your Jun 4 comment, you say "not enough to warrant learning", and "[otherwise] I'm screwed]". From another perspective, I hope you can see how someone might get the idea that you come here with a sense of entitlement. I'm sure that's not the case, but perception is a powerful thing, no?

Comment: @Seamus I'm here because I've done a lot of pick and shovel work and found nothing, I even confessed I may have overlooked something, so I posted here to see if anyone had any knowledge that I do not, I'm not asking for someone to write a  program for me, and I didn't comehere to get psychoanalysed, I came here for help.

Comment: And I'm not offering any psychoanalysis - apparently you've misunderstood what I said. I simply suggested you try to look at your request from another perspective.

Comment: @Seamus well you aren't offering help nor any kind of advice either, so what exactly is it that you are doing? Trying to make yourself seem like an intellectual by dissecting a simple question for some subtext and hidden meaning? Because there isn't any friend. Look at it from another perspective to achieve what exactly? Save it for psych class buddy.

Comment: @JayBuckel: I will... thanks for the advice! Some might take a clue from the overwhelming replies you've received to date on your question.

Answer (score -1):

So in the end I just learned to code Python (somewhat) and learned how the read and write scripts worked, I then tinkered with the read script and kind of merged the two scripts together. The new script reads the input of the first card and then waits for an input of a blank second card to write the captured UID to.

Comment: It would be courteous to the next person searching for a solution, if you could provide the code to your solution, as this answer is not helpful.

Comment: [The following shell script](https://gist.github.com/sam1902/f401e036bbd6306b6a46345bf16301ad) might be a good starting point. You can also checkout [this repo](https://github.com/nfc-tools/miLazyCracker) which is of tremedous help. Cheerio